# How do I run a select query with count()?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

```
account_users
-----
id | primary_key

posts
-----
post_id | primary_key
author | foreign key to account_users.id
```

Let's say I have 2 tables.  account_users has the users. posts holds the posts.

How can I select all users where count(*) of posts are more than 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT au.*,p.*
FROM account_users au
INNER JOIN posts p
ON p.account_users.id = au.id
GROUP BY p.post_id
HAVING count(*) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

@Timex

try below query.

```
Select au.ID from account_users au
inner join posts p on au.ID = p.author
Group By au.ID
having COUNT(p.post_id) > 5
```